# SQL server 'OR' query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

Is this query optimized?

```
SELECT 
        ElementID,
    AVID,
        ElementName
FROM 
    Element
WHERE  
    AVID = 36 OR  AVID = 56 OR  AVID = 57 OR  AVID = 58 OR  AVID = 59 OR  AVID = 60 
    OR  AVID = 61 OR  AVID = 74 OR  AVID = 208 OR  AVID = 220 OR  AVID = 304 
    OR  AVID = 263 OR  AVID = 416 OR  AVID = 250 OR  AVID = 335 OR  AVID = 150 
    OR  AVID = 356 OR  AVID = 362 OR  AVID = 382 OR  AVID = 404 OR  AVID = 609 
    OR  AVID = 642 OR  AVID = 643 OR  AVID = 572 OR  AVID = 656 OR  AVID = 678 
    OR  AVID = 685 OR  AVID = 697 OR  AVID = 766 OR  AVID = 786 OR  AVID = 629
```

`AVID` is a foreign key in the table. `ElementID` is the primary key. The values of `AVID` are generated by the UI as per user choices so unable to use JOINS. I receive `AVID` as comma separated values (csv) and I have small utility which generates this query using `AVID` csv. Count of these `AVID` goes beyond 1000.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and query is being executed from a web browser interface so stored procedure is not going to help me.

So I would like to know if this query is optimized or how it can be further optimized?

Comment: Why don't you use `IN`? It's certainly more readable, and shouldn't affect performance. Might even be faster, as it should make easier for the query analyzer to optimize execution. Anyway, my guess is that there isn't much to optimize in the query itself, it's the index that will make the difference.

Comment: IN has limitation when number of comparison goes beyond certain limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there will be a performance hit when you need to filter by a huge number of AVIDs.

With this amount you are good to go.

As a curiosity, you could also use the "IN" operator, which would transform your query to something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Element WHERE AVID IN (1, 2, 3, ...)
```

Also, if you see a performance penalty due to the amount of AVIDs you are using, you should try to insert the AVIDs in a temporary table and then use a inner join to finally filter.

It would be something like this for T-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP_TBL (AVID_TMP INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO #TMP_TBL (AVID_TMP) VALUES (1), (2), (3), ...

SELECT e.* 
FROM ELEMENT e
INNER JOIN #TMP_TBL t ON t.AVID_TMP = e.AVID
```

Or like this for MySQL:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_tbl AS (SELECT * FROM element)

INSERT INTO tmp_tbl VALUES (1), (2), (3)...

SELECT e.* 
FROM ELEMENT e
INNER JOIN #TMP_TBL t ON t.AVID_TMP = e.AVID
```

And that's it. You would be good to go.
You do not need to drop this table, as it is temporary it will get dropped automatically when the connection is closed.

Check these links:

OR Operator: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188361.aspx

IN Operator (give special attention to Remarks section): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx

Comment: temp table #TMP_TBL should be created in DB or it gets automatically created when the above query is executed?

Comment: mmm, that syntax is for T-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server), I will edit the post to make it MySQL friendly

Comment: I am not using My-SQL... it is T-SQL..SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: No problem. Do not forget to read the links, as they provide good info